# How to find Galois group modulo prime

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Excuse my ignorance but how do you find the Galois group of an algebraic equation with integer coefficients modulo a prime number $ x^5+x+1\equiv 0\  \text{mod 5} $, say. Is there a Galois resolvent for this?

And if there is, how do you factorize an equation modulo prime, in case it hasn't got any of the p roots modulo prime, in quadratic and cubic degree polynomials or whatnot degree other than 1 say?

Many thanks.

Comment: You say rational coefficients, but tagged this as finite fields and talk about working modulo prime numbers. That sounds a bit confused. Also, we have $2^5+2+1\equiv_50$ so that's a solution modulo 5, which gives a factoring $x^5+x+1\equiv_5(x-2)q(x)$ for some forth-degree $q$.

Comment: I don't know about factoring *equations*, but univariate polynomials can be factored modulo $p$ (or over any finite field) somewhat efficiently with for example [the Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm).

Comment: Don't delete your question after receiving an answer. It's unkind
to those who take the time to answer your questions and it makes is appear as
though you are trying to hide something. I've rolled back this question to an earlier edit.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the splitting field of $f(X) \in \mathbb F_p[X]$ is $\mathbb F_{p^n}$, where $n$ is the smallest such that $f$ divides $X^{p^n}-X$ in $\mathbb F_p[X]$. Moreover, $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ is a cyclic extension of $\mathbb F_{p}$.